# Dynamic Form Field Submit Handler

Tags: forms, ajax

This form creates dynamic fields. I am trying to build a submit handler for each of the dynamic field values.  So for each of the $form['items_fieldset'][$i]['serial'], (amount, and description) I could have many fields.  How would I pass those to my database?

Here's what I have thusfar:

Form excerpt:

```
$form['#tree'] = TRUE;

$form['items_fieldset'] = array(
'#type' => 'fieldset',
'#title' => t('Shippment Inventory Items:'),
'#prefix' => '<div id="items-fieldset-wrapper">',
'#suffix' => '</div>',
); 

 if (empty($form_state['num_items'])) {
$form_state['num_items'] = 1;
} 


 for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['num_items']; $i++) {

$form['items_fieldset'][$i] = array(
'#prefix' => '<div class="two-col">',
'#suffix' => '</div>'
);

$form['items_fieldset'][$i]['amount'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#size' => 30,
  '#title' => t('Amount:'),
  '#required' => FALSE,
  '#prefix' => '<div style="float:left; padding-right: 50px;">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);

$form['items_fieldset'][$i]['description'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#size' => 50,
  '#title' => t('Description:'),
  '#required' => FALSE,
  '#prefix' => '<div style="float:left; padding-right: 50px;">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
); 

$form['items_fieldset'][$i]['serial'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#size' => 30,
  '#title' => t('Serial Number:'),
  '#required' => FALSE,
  '#prefix' => '<div style="float:left;">',
  '#suffix' => '</div><div style="clear:both;"></div>',
);
} 

$form['items_fieldset']['add_items'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Add more'),
'#submit' => array('_nnreport_shipping_new_add_one'),
'#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => '_nnreport_shipping_new_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'items-fieldset-wrapper',
    ),
);
```

Handler to pass to database (not including all the static form values):

```
 function _nnreport_shipping_new_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $submission = new stdClass();
    //This doesnt work, but I think it's kinda what I'm after...?? 
     for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['num_items']; $i++) {
          $submission=>amount.$i = $form_state['values']['$i']['amount'];

          };
          _nnreport_shipping_new_update($submission); }
```

After that I submit the values of $submission to the database, like this:

```
function _nnreport_shipping_new_update(&$submission){

     db_insert('nnj_shipment')
        ->fields(array(
            'hotshotId' => $submission->carrier,
            'driver' => $submission->driver,
            'driverPhone' => $submission->driverPhone,
             //lots more of those...
              ))
             ->execute();
```

I've unsuccessfully tried a few variations to get the dynamic fields into the object...I would be very grateful for someone to point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after ignoring this problem for a while it was time to find an answer.

The issue was with using $form['#tree'] = TRUE; 
I didn't use the full array references after that...eg:
$form_state[$i]['description'] needed to be
$form_state['values']['items_fieldset'][$i]['description'] = 'foo';
(

After that I just used a foreach to grab my values from the dynamic field values...like:
foreach ($form_state['values']['items_fieldset'] as $v){
$submission->description[] = $v['description'];
}

And last was to dump them into my DB, and life is good.